# Jquery attribute code to Javascript attribute code

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes

I have a scenario in my project where I should not use Jquery code(unfortunately). I am little good in writing jquery code but not javascript code.

functionality:

```
1.I have few disabled controls on page with attribute clickdisabled=disable.    
2. I am trying to set title to all elements with that attribute on a page(s). 
3. when user clicks on disabled controls alert that controls title.
4. I am trying to make click on disabled controls
```

Any help to make my java script code same as jquery code and make it working.

Jquery code

```
function DisableControlAction() {
   $('[clickdisabled=disable]').attr("title", "You are not authorized to perform this action.");

    $('[clickdisabled=disable]').removeAttr("disabled"); // to enable click for server controls

    $('[clickdisabled=disable]').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert($(this).attr("title"));
        return false;
    });
}
```

Java script code I am trying

```
function DisableControlAction() {
document.getElementsByTagName('[clickdisabled=disable]').setAttribute("title", "You are not authorized to perform this action.");
document.getElementsByTagName('[clickdisabled=disable]').removeAttribute("disabled");
document.getElementsByTagName('[clickdisabled=disable]').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert($(this).getAttribute("title"));
        return false;
    });
}
```

Comment: Well step 1 is to note that `.getElementsByTagName()` expects to select elements by..well, *tag name* - like "div" or "a". So it won't work with `'[clickdisabled=disable]'`. Try using [`document.querySelectorAll('[clickdisabled=disable]')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll) instead, and using a loop to process each element that it returns.

Comment: Even if that would have worked, you can not set attributes to a node collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use querySelectorAll() and get the list of elements through whatever means. You can use element.disabled = true; and it will disable the input

[Codepen example](http://codepen.io/tourn171/pen/jEmRRW)

```js
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input");

for(i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++){
  inputs[i].disabled = true;
}
```